# set FragmentPagerAdapter to ViewPager for add fragments programmatically

Tags: android, android-fragments

This is my activity xml layout where i've put an viewPager for show tab below a relativeLayout

```
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/WordContainer"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <!-- Titolo -->
            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:id="@+id/txtParola"/>
            <!-- tipo -->
            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/txtTipo"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                                       android:id="@+id/pager"
                                       android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                       android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

this is my FragmentPagerAdapter implementation

```
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I want to add fragments to the viewPager programmatically but how i can do this from my main_activity?

(I can't extends the main_activity with FragmentActivity because i need a simple activity implementation for accessing to the TextViews)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you are trying to implement swipe views with action bar tabs. Here is the basic steps that you need to do:

1. In your main activity, inflate the layout xml file and get a reference to the ViewPager defined in the xml.

   mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
2. In your main activity, create a TabsPagerAdapater, and set the adapter of the ViewPager with the TabsPagerAdapter

   mPagerAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
   mViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
3. Each tab view is actually presented by a fragment which is created in getItem() of TabsPagerAdapter. Here is how you do in program:

   public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
       MyFragment myFragment;
       String[] mTitles = {"Tab1", "Tab2", "Tab3"}

   ```
   public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
       super(fm);
   }

   @Override
   public Fragment getItem(int index) {

       // Create the fragment here. Assuming you already have a fragment class
       // called "MyFragment", you just need to instantiate an 
       // instance of MyFragment and return it

       myFragment = new MyFragment();
       return myFragment;
   }

   @Override
   public int getCount() {
       // Return the number of tabs, assuming you have 3 tabs here.
       return mTitles.length;
   }

   @Override 
   public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) 
       // Return the title of each tab
       // Assuming title string are stored in mTitle array
       // 
       return mTitles[position];
   }
   ```

   }

Hope it helps.

Comment: I think the OP question is regarding adding dynamically fragment to view pager?